# Private lodging rental search engine

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, rental, airbnb

There are a lot of websites where people can rent out lodging (peer to peer rental): Airbnb, 9flats, roomorama, Wimdu ... Trying to find the best place is difficult because you have to access every website to compare. Somebody told me that there is a search engine (meta-search) where you can find a lot of places at the same time, but I can't remember the name and can't find it.

Is there a such website?

If so, which P2P rental sites are included and which excluded (so to be searched ' by hand')?

Answer (score 2):

[Padmapper](http://www.padmapper.com/) aggregates AirBnB, Craigslist and more traditional sites for America, Canada and the United Kingdom. In general these sites target different areas which is probably why a global search engine doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, I was looking for a more general site, but this is a good reference to travel to USA